# Error: before token on <stdio.h>

Tags: c, compiler-errors

I have been trying to compile my code but when in compilation, I receive the error:

hw02.c:1:9: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘<’ token include "stdio.h

Here is the code I am trying to run. I am new to coding using C and I am not sure if it is because I don't need to have included  or I am missing something very simple.

```
//hw 02.q2.c
#include <stdio.h>
#define subm(a,b) ((a)-(b))
#define cubem(a) (a*a*a)
#define minm(a,b) (((a)<=(b))?(a):(b))
#define oddm(a) (((a)%2==0)?0:1)
int main()
 {
int a = 5, b = 7;
printf("%d - %d : %d", a, b,  subf(a, b));
printf("%d - %d : %d", a, b, subm(a, b));
printf("%d - %d : %d", a, b, subf(a++, b--));
printf("%d - %d,: %d", a, b,  subm(a++, b--));

printf("%d,", cubef(a));
printf("%d,", cubem(a));
printf("%d,", cubef(--a));
printf("%d", cubem(--a));

printf("%d,", minf(a, b));
printf("%d,", minm(a, b));
printf("%d,", minf(--a, --b));
printf("%d", minm(--a, --b));

printf("%d,", oddf(a));
printf("%d,", oddm(a));
printf("%d,", oddf(a++));
printf("%d", oddm(a++));

return 0;
}int subf(int a, int b) {
return a - b;
}
int cubef(int a) {
return a * a *a;
}
int minf(int a, int b) {
if (a <= b) {
    return a;
}
else {
    return b;
}
}
int oddf(int a) {
if (a % 2 == 0) {
    return 0;
}
else {
    return 1;
}
}
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: what system and compiler are you using to compile?
check for paths

Comment: Your code, as posted, compiles and runs at ideone.  I'm uncertain how the code with which you encountered the error differs, but we can help only with what you present to use.

Comment: I suspect the code shown is not the one producing the error. `#include <stdio.h>` is on line 2, not line 1

Comment: MSVC only objects to the lack of function prototypes.

Comment: Unrelated, you seriously need to turn up your compiler warnings. You have a [*plethora* of sequence-point issues](https://pastebin.com/wbumkMfM) in this code.

Comment: ... but none of those explain the error reported.

Comment: What happens if you remove the C++ style comment in the beginning

Comment: MSVC output is `5 - 7 : -25 - 7 : -25 - 7 : -26 - 6,: 0343,343,216,273,3,2,00,0,0,1` whatever that is about. Despite compiler warnings, the undeclared functions do take and return `int` values.

Comment: Could there be a Byte Order Mark in the file?

Comment: I have been using PuTTY to compile my program

Comment: PuTTY is a terminal emulator, not a compiler. Which commands did you use?

Comment: Unrelated, but you should have `#define cubem(a) ((a)*(a)*(a))` to avoid unpleasant surprises in the event of something like `cubem(x + 1)`.

Answer (score 2):

First, you have to use functions prototypes or put all the functions before the main because when the compiler compile your file and meets an undeclared function calls it raises an

> implicit declaration of function ‘xyz’

Second, you should use `/* comments */` syntax instead of `//comments` syntax, because `//comments` are c++ style.

Comment: Many c compilers are happy with c++ style comments

Comment: They are perfectly standard C comments starting from C99!

Comment: Agreed, I only use the `/* ... */` style to comment out blocks of code. Using `//..` style locally allows this, a nice feature of C.

Comment: And the lack of function prototypes isn't a problem, since the parameters and function values are `int` anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is a silly observation, but did you tryied:

```
/*w 02.q2.c*/
#include <stdio.h>
```

instead of:

```
//hw 02.q2.c
#include <stdio.h>
```

[Check this](https://www.techonthenet.com/c_language/comments.php)

Comment: It's not silly at all, if you're using strict C code, comments go `/* like this */`, the `//` syntax is from C++

Comment: @yorodm thanks a lot for comment, now my answer get a lot more of sense, I should explain that, but I'm not that good in C or C++ so I tryed to say the minimun to not srew it up haha

Comment: @KeineLust You mean the `// comment` style.

Comment: @KeineLust +1 for reminding me to check my standards :D

Comment: @EugeneSh. yes!!

Comment: So Maybe that's not the root of the problem here... :/

Comment: I fixed the comments to have /* and they still produce the same error when I try to compile...

Comment: @TaylorColeman either the code posted is not your actual code, or there is a rogue character somewhere in the source text, and text editors do sometimes have a bug resulting in this, in my experience.

Comment: @TaylorColeman, try to close and open the IDE where you are working at C, reopen it and then run it with all the changed suggested

Comment: @DamianLattenero I would say even without changes. Just copy and paste the code *from the question* into a new file, save and compile.